# Javascript code running function more than once

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make an area calculator for a trapezoid using html and js. My code is shown below, but for some reason I am not getting correct answers out of this. I suspect that is because the code is running the function more than once, but I'm not really sure.

```js
function solveArea() {
  var base1, base2, height, area;
  base1 = document.getElementById("base1").value;
  base2 = document.getElementById("base2").value;
  height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  area = ((base1 + base2) / 2) * height;
  document.getElementById("area").value = area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="base1" type="number" placeholder="Base 1">
  <input id="base2" type="number" placeholder="Base 2">
  <input id="height" type="number" placeholder="Height">
  <input id="area" type="number" readonly="" placeholder="Area">
  <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="solveArea()">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById().value` is a string, so when you use the `+` operator it will concatenate the two operands. In your case, you should convert strings to numbers (*e.g.* with the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function):

```js
function solveArea() {
  let base1 = Number(document.getElementById("base1").value);
  let base2 = Number(document.getElementById("base2").value);
  let height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
  let area = (base1 + base2) / 2 * height;
  document.getElementById("area").value = area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="base1" type="number" placeholder="Base 1">
  <input id="base2" type="number" placeholder="Base 2">
  <input id="height" type="number" placeholder="Height">
  <input id="area" type="number" readonly placeholder="Area">
  <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="solveArea()">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parseInt

```
        function solveArea(){
            var base1, base2, height, area;
            base1= parseInt(document.getElementById("base1").value, 10);
            base2= parseInt(document.getElementById("base2").value, 10);
            height= parseInt(document.getElementById("height").value, 10);
            area = ((base1 + base2) / 2)* height;
            document.getElementById("area").value = area;
        }
```

Comment: Always provide a [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description), from the docs: "Be careful—this does not default to 10! If the radix value is not of the Number type it will be coerced to a Number"  `base1=parseInt(document.getElementById("base1").value, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

your code is not running multiple times,
the problem is when you do

```
base1= document.getElementById("base1").value;
base2= document.getElementById("base2").value;
console.log(base1+base2)
```

and base1 = 1 and base2 = 1
then the output will be

```
11
```

So you are receiving the value as a string so just **convert it to the number** and your code will work fine.

```
function solveArea(){
  var base1, base2, height, area;
  base1= document.getElementById("base1").value;
  base2= document.getElementById("base2").value;
  height= document.getElementById("height").value;
  area = ((+base1 + +base2) / 2)*height;
  document.getElementById("area").value = area;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the input values as numbers using either `parseFloat` or `Number` then you should be bale to perform the basic arithmetic operations you need. Without parsing these numbers they were being treated as strings. The issue with `parseInt` in this regard is that it would prevent you from using numbers such as 5.25 for input ~ it would be treated as 5...

```js
function solveArea() {
  var base1, base2, height, area;
  base1 = Number(document.getElementById("base1").value);
  base2 = Number(document.getElementById("base2").value);
  height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
  area = ((base1 + base2) / 2) * height;
  document.getElementById("area").value = area;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="base1" type="number" placeholder="Base 1">
  <input id="base2" type="number" placeholder="Base 2">
  <input id="height" type="number" placeholder="Height">
  <input id="area" type="number" readonly="" placeholder="Area">
  <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="solveArea()">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```